# can I say consult with doctor?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, meaning

I am writing this sentence

> Patients need to have consultation with doctors.

is it correct to say *consultation with doctors* or it would be better to say

> Patients need to consult an appointment with doctors

Comment: Could you explain more about what meaning you're trying to convey? What is *Patients need to have consultation with doctors* meant to mean? The patients need to book appointments before doing something else? That if you are unwell you need to visit a doctor? Another meaning?

Comment: I would say: **to make an appointment with doctors** or **to consult doctors**. **To have a consultation with doctor** is also correct.

Comment: @starsplusplus i am trying to say that patients need to be with doctors. in other words, they need the doctors to help them and fix their bodies

Comment: Do you mean that ill people need to see doctors in order to get help? If you are a [patient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patient) you are already receiving or waiting to receive medical treatment.

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

> Patients need to have **consultations** with doctors.

In this example, *consultations* is used as a noun.

> Patients need to consult an appointment with doctors.

is incorrect because you can't *consult* (discuss information or advice) with an *appointment*, which is the object in this sentence. You would have to reorder it a bit:

> Patients need an appointment to consult with doctors.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence sounds correct. Word *[consultation](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consultation)* is regularly used for this purpose.

To [consult](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consult) means:

> to ask for information or advice from someone because it is their job to know something

or

> to discuss something with someone so that you can make a decision together

or

> to look for information in a book, map, list etc.

(Ref. LDOCE)

So, you can't really *consult an [appointment](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/appointment)*. The 2nd sentence would have to be rephrased to be correct. With the word *appointment* you can use: *make*, *set*, *have* etc. (*have* fits your example best, I think).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is fine. You may be able to shorten it slightly, since "have a consultation with" is synonymous with "consult", you could say "Patients need to consult a doctor".

Singular "a doctor" probably works better here, but it depends on context, and consider whether "need" or "should" is more appropriate.